# Getting pagination arrows together

Tags: css, html, pagination

I'm trying to get pagination arrows on a HTML5 page.

CSS:

```
.arrow {
    padding : 18px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="arrow">&laquo;</a>
<a href="" class="arrow">&raquo;</a>
```

However the arrows show up in two separate lines.

How do I get them to be in one line? I'm using Firefox.

Comment: What if you try putting them into a container and setting a width?

Comment: I ran the code you showed and it placed them on the same line.  Use your browser's inspector to see if there are inherited CSS rules that are overriding yours.

Comment: is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/cbtbyxeh/, check if you have other css rules causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

One may want to put the pagination within a container. Just wrap your unordered list in something that has a defined width and add the class, .pagination-centered.

Hope this helps!

P.S. I agree with Adjit.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the first version of this question so I know your arrows are in pre tag. So either remove space between these to arrows so it should be

```
<pre><a href="#" class="arrow">&laquo;</a><a href="#" class="arrow">&raquo;</a></pre>
```

And not

```
<pre>
<a href="#" class="arrow">&laquo;</a>
<a href="#" class="arrow">&raquo;</a>
</pre>
```

Or just remove your pre tag.

The pre tag defines preformatted text and every new line in your code will be a new line on the loaded page. Your arrows were in two separate lines and you had empty space between your arrows when the page loaded.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r9jn8r2f/3/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had to change display to "inline": and also get more specific with the css: #baseid a.arrow . I was surprised since .arrow would be unique.